# How to collect a text value that is between two other objects using ' cheerio '?

Tags: css-selectors, cheerio

The sitemap looks like this:

[image]

When trying to recover in general:

```
var Result = $('h3.thick.scoretime').text().trim();
```

The result is this:

```
FT
1 - 0
(HT 1 - 0)
```

I tried to use the search by `child`:

```
var Result = $('h3.thick.scoretime:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
```

But the result is blank:

```
Expected result:
```

1 - 0

How should I proceed in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove the spans:

```
$('.scoretime span').remove()
```

now it's in:

```
$('.scoretime').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total texts with

```
var TotalText = $('h3.thick.scoretime').text()
```

Then get the texts in child nodes with

```
var ChildTexts = $('h3.thick.scoretime span.match-state').text()
```

And then replace the `ChildTexts` in `TotalText` with `''` so that parent node text only will remain.
BTW `'h3.thick.scoretime'` and `'h3.thick.scoretime:nth-child(2)'` are CSS Selectors, not XPath expressions.

Comment: Hello friend @Prophet , first of all thank you very much for the support and for the time used for this. I've already adjusted the tags, removing xpath and adding CSS selector. In the model you indicated, I have to do a loop to remove the value of the first child and second child, I believe that Cheerio has something a little more direct without this need. I'll look into other options a little more!

Comment: OK, I'm absolutely not familiar with cheerio so I wrote only what I do know :)

Comment: I thank you very much for that example @Prophet , you gave me an interesting approach for my future uses, I never stopped to think about this option to replace, it was very important!